# Is it possible to know when you're "inside" a symlink?

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link

In Windows, is it possible to know when you're "inside" a symlink?

For example -- let's say I have a symlink at C:\foo\ that links to D:\foo. When browsing the C:\ drive and then double-clicking on "foo", it appears visually that I'm still within the C:\ drive (C:\foo), when I'm actually seeing data stored at D:\foo --

Without knowing/realizing that I had jumped through a symlink, is it possible to see or know when such has happened?

Answer (score 0):

If you install the fantastic [**Link Shell Extension**](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html), it will add the following overlay icons by default:

- Overlay Icons for Hardlinks:

  [image: 1]
- Overlay Icons for Junctions:

  [image: 2]
- Overlay Icons for Symbolic Links:

  [image: 3]

The extension also allows you complete freedom to customise the icons if you like:

[image: 4]

This will allow you to easily distinguish the above from normal files/folders.